# Cannot find the file specified | SSIS | Execute Package SSIS using Dtexec on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, dtexec

I have a doubt about Package SSIS.

I am loading an information from an Excel file to a table on the SQL Server using SSIS. My file is on the Desktop and the package is successfully executed using Dtexec but nothing happens, if you change the file's directory to my documents, the file is executed successfully and the information is loaded into the table. What must be happening?

```
1º C: \ Users \ BMIGUEL \ Desktop \ SMIC \ 29090.xlsx

2nd C: \ Users \ Public \ Documents \ SMIC_FILES \ 29090 \ 29090.xlsx
```

Comment: Looked at the errors in the SSISDB Logs, they will tell you why. I suspect that the SQL Server service account does not have access to the directory; and nor should it have access to your documents folder.

Comment: To follow up on Larnu's excellent insight, whenever I work with SSIS, I always ensure a consistent directory structure exists and that the service account the powers SQL Server has access to it. For me, that usually looks like `C:\ssisdata\OperationalArea\Input`, `C:\ssisdata\OperationalArea\Output`  and `C:\ssisdata\OperationalArea\Archive` where OperationalArea is things like Sales, HR, etc

Comment: to even further both Larnu and billinkc... a lot of times you are using a fileshare directory for people that cannot access the server to drop files. in that case your file is located in \\\[IP or servername]\directory\filename. This model often occurs in DEV/TEST/PROD environments. This is almost certainly an access issue.

Comment: Also, remember that mapped directories are specific to the user, so Agent does not see your mapped directories. use the full path if possible.